# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = n^2 \left( 1- \cos \frac{x^3 - 1}{n} \right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let
>
> $$f_n(x) = n^2 \left( 1- \cos \frac{x^3 - 1}{n} \right)$$
>
> Let M be the set of x s.t. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$
>   exists. For each $x \in M$ let $f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$. Then
>
> 1. M is bounded above
> 2. f(x) is even function
> 3. f(x) has slant asymptote
> 4. $f'(1) = 6$
> 5. 1-4 are false.

The only thing I see now is that $1 \in M$. Please, give me hints how to deal with this problem.

---

Update: I try to use L'Hopital's rule

$$\lim \left(x^{3}-1\right)\sin\frac{x^{3}-1}{n}/\frac{2}{n^{2}}\rightarrow \lim \left(x^{3}-1\right)^{2}\cos\frac{x^{3}-1}{n}/\frac{4}{n^{2}}=\infty$$

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hospital's rules?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar. I tried it but the limit became more tangled. I try it again now.

Comment: **Hint:** $\dfrac{1-\cos t}2=\sin^2\dfrac t2$ , and $\dfrac{\sin u}u\to1$ as $u\to0$.

Comment: You can use the limit $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^2} = \frac{1}{2}$ and substitute $y=\frac{x^3-1}{n}$

Comment: Malicious hint: you can easily answer 2. And if 2 turns out to be false, you can conclude 5.

Comment: are you preparing to the NES exams? )))))

Comment: @KanyeWest, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $x\neq 1$ (the limit is easy to calculate for $x=1$, you can calculate the limit by writing $f(x)$ as $$f(x) = \frac{1-\cos\frac{x^3-1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}},$$
then applying L'Hospital's rule twice.

Alternatively, you can use Taylor's expansion of $\cos$ to cancel some terms out.

Comment: Please, see update: L'Hopital gives me $\infty$.

Comment: @Yaldc Redo your differentiation. Differentiate $1-\cos\frac{x^3-1}{n}$ with respect to $n$. Remember, you also have to differentiate $\frac{1}{n}$ that is INSIDE (*composite functions!*) the $\cos$ function.

Comment: yes, I remember. $-1/n^2$ will cancel out the same term in the denominator!

Comment: Here is detailed version: $-\frac{x^{3}-1}{n^{2}}\sin\frac{x^{3}-1}{n}/-\frac{2}{n^{4}}$

Comment: Correct. However, you also have to differentiate the denominator to get $\frac{-2}{n^3}$!

Comment: But I've already differentiated it! It was $1/n^2$ and became $-2/n^4$

Comment: $1/n^2$ differentiates into $-2/n^3$, not $n^4$.

Comment: Oh, right. Now I got the same answer as other participants wrote. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it is easy to see that 
$\cos \frac{x^{3}-1}{n} = 1 - \frac{(\frac{x^{3}-1}{n})^{2}}{2} + ... = 1 - \frac{x^{6} - 2x^{3} + 1}{2n^{2}} + ...$ so that $f(x) = n^{2} (1-\cos \frac{x^{3}-1}{n}) \rightarrow \frac{x^{6}}{2} - x^{3} + \frac{1}{2}$

so 1 - false, 2 - false, 3 - false, 4 - false

Comment: Thank you but I'm bad at using all kinds of approximations. So I try to find out solutions that (1) I understand and (2) I'll be able to replicate on exam.

Comment: it is just Taylor series.
i think it is the easiest way to solve this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $1 - \cos(x) \approx\frac{x^2}{2}$ for small $x$. Thus,
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(\frac{x^3 - 1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n^2}} \approx \frac{(x^3 - 1)^2}{2} $$
for large $n$. To make this argument rigorous, use Taylor's theorem or L'Hopital rule.

Answer (score 0):

Make the change of variable $\frac{x^3-1}n=\epsilon$, so that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\big(1-\cos\frac{x^3-1}n\big)=(x^3-1)^2\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1-cos\epsilon}{\epsilon^2}.$$
The latter limit is a constant that can be computed by L'Hospital ($\to\frac{\sin\epsilon}{2\epsilon}\to\frac{\cos\epsilon}2\to\frac12$).

[For rigor, limits to $0^+$ or $0^-$ should be used depending on the sign of $x^3-1$, but given that the function is even with respect to $\epsilon$, this makes no difference.]